# Unstable BCLK/PCIe clock + 4 hard drive failures in 6 weeks after move. Replaced Mobo+CPU but Issue persist & new HDDs failed

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure, hard-drive-failure, storage-spaces

I'm having several issues that I believe are related. The issues began when I moved the computer to a new house 6 weeks ago.

- The Bus Clock (BCLK & PCI Clock) of my CPU runs ~2Mhz lower than whats set in BIOS and is in constant flux between 97 to 99MHz. If I set 98 in BIOS, it bounces between 95-98.  If I set 103, it bounces between 97 and 103. ON BOTH MOTHERBOARDS (more on this later).
- I've experienced 4 Hard Disk failures since this issue started.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yf7qZIZJBBU

I've been switching out hardware in an attempt to figure out the cause of the BCLK issue which I'm concerned is causing the SATA bus clock to fluctuate and the drives to fail. The Mobo and CPU have been replaced and the issue still exists. The BCLK issue is also present without any PCI cards installed, any HDDs connected, and only a single stick of ram installed + SSDs needed to boot Windows.  As of now, the only constants are the PSU, SSDs, case+fans, mouse+keyboard, and the same Windows 10 install.

I'd have liked to immediately rule out the PSU, but it seems supply has been affected by COVID19.  I was going to build a whole new PC, but again, there's nothing in stock.
I was only just able to order an in stock `CORSAIR HX Series HX750` today and it won't be here for over a week.  But right now my data stored on these HDDs is in jeopardy and I'm not sure if the PSU is the culprit because it's voltages are in spec and it appears to handle load without an issue. However I don't have an Oscilloscope to rule it out.
**EDIT:** Apparently I'm not getting a new PSU...

> We regret to inform you that upon processing your order, our warehouse found that the last unit we have left is damaged and not suitable to fulfill your order. We apologize for the inconvenience. Thank you for your understanding

Original Hardware when the issues started:

```
PSU: Rosewill CAPSTONE Series 450W 80 Plus Gold
Mobo: ASRock z77 Extreme4 
      (Note: Enabling spread-spectrum surprisingly would stabilize the clock fluctuations to within a single MHz, 
             however it still ran -2MHz under what was set in BIOS) 
CPU: i7-3770k @ 4.4GHz @ 102.4Mhz Bus Clock 
    (Note: 102.4*43=4403Mhz and was originally part of the overclock.
           But afterwords it was needed to achieve ~100Mhz+-0.7 with spread-spectrum.
           Without spread-spectrum clock would swing between 97 and 102.4 and every where in between)
Memory:  Slots 0 & 2: Crucial Ballistix Sport XT 16GB Kit 8GBx2 DDR3 1600 MT/s PC3-12800 CL9
         Slots 1 & 3: Corsair CMZ16GX3M2A1600C10 Vengeance 16GB (2x8GB)
PCIe16x GPU: Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1070 G1
PCIe1x:      I/O Crest 4 Port SATA III PCI-e 2.0 x1 Controller Card
PCI:         Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi XtremeGamer
SSDs: C:\ Samsung 850 EVO 500GB
      A:\ Samsung 850 EVO 500GB
      D:\ (Stripped StoragePool) Samsung 840 EVO 250GB + Crucial M4 256GB
HDDs: Connected via SATA Controller card and managed by Windows Storage Spaces
      HGST 4TB HDN724040ALE640 @ 46,6522hrs(5.31yrs) 
      HGST 4TB HDN724040ALE640 @ 31,859hrs(3.64yrs)
      (failed) HGST 4TB HDN726040ALE614 @ 16,014hrs(1.83yrs)
      (failed) Seagate 4TB ST4000DM005 @ 12,000hrs(1.36yrs)
```

Hardware changes since issue began are listed below. I thought the issue was the mobo and had found a deal on a used mobo+cpu combo to hold over until Zen3 is released.
*[Full disclosure]: I had no choice, I thought maybe there was dirt in the socket or the pins weren't making proper contact after the jostling from the move. My attempt to clean it bent pins and rendered RAM slots 0 & 2 unusable and somehow broke Intel TurboBoost & the unlocked multiplier. CPU was stuck at 3.5Ghz which is actually 3395Mhz with the BCLK issue. I had hoped this would solve the BCLK issue I suspect to be causing the Hard Drive IO Errors and failures.

**EDIT: Apparently this isn't clear? I replaced the Mobo + CPU after this with the hardware below. The BCLK issue is still present with the new motherboard.***

```
PSU: (In progress) CORSAIR HX Series HX750 
Mobo: MSI Z97s Krait Edition
      (Note: This mobo has no spread-spectrum option. 
             Attempts to set BCLK higher just increase how far BCLK swings upwards from 97MHz.
             The option to unlink PCIe freq from BCLK is greyed out and doesn't appear to be configurable)
CPU: i7-4790k @ stock 
HDDS: I've replaced all SATA cables with new expensive cables. The current state is:
      HGST Deskstar 4TB HDN724040ALE640 @ 46,6522hrs(5.31yrs) [currently connected]
      HGST Deskstar 4TB HDN724040ALE640 @ 31,859hrs(3.64yrs) [currently connected]
      (failed) HGST Deskstar 4TB HDN726040ALE614 @ 16,014hrs(1.83yrs) 
      (failed) Seagate Barracuda 4TB ST4000DM005 @ 12,000hrs(1.36yrs) 
      (failed) HGST Ultrastar 4TB HUS724040ALE640 @ ~30 minutes (WinDFT failed quick surface test)
      (failed) WD Gold 6TB Enterprise Class WD6003FRYZ @ 297hrs(12days) [currently connected]
```

While moving a Steam game from the SSD storage pool to the HDD storage pool, the WD Enterprise Gold failed with an alarming sound unlike anything I've heard before. I've never heard what a "Head Crash" sounds like, but I'd imagine that's what one would sound like.  Windows immediately notified of Physical Disk Failure and the event log displayed a Disk Hardware Error.  That original error report has dropped off the log already due to the shear volume of disk errors per second (Windows Explorer is painfully slow right now.) [image: )]

With the exception of the Dead-On-Arrival HGST Ultrastar, no drive has reported any SMART error. Not even the WD Gold that StorageSpaces currently reports as failed.

- `cmd> wmic diskdrive get status`: reports all drives `OK`
- `cmd> wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi path MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus`: does not predict that any currently connected drive will fail soon.
- `PS> Get-PhysicalDisk` states:

```
Number FriendlyName              MediaType CanPool OperationalStatus            HealthStatus Usage            Size
------ ------------              --------- ------- -----------------            ------------ -----            ----
4      Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB SSD       True    OK                           Healthy      Auto-Select 465.76 GB
2      WDC WD6003FRYZ-01F0DB0    HDD       False   {Failed Media, IO Error, OK} Unhealthy    Retired       5.46 TB
3      Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB SSD       False   OK                           Healthy      Auto-Select 232.75 GB
0      HGST HDN724040ALE640      HDD       False   OK                           Healthy      Auto-Select   3.64 TB
1      HGST HDN724040ALE640      HDD       False   OK                           Healthy      Auto-Select   3.64 TB
6      Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB SSD       True    OK                           Healthy      Auto-Select 465.76 GB
5      M4-CT256M4SSD2            SSD       False   OK                           Healthy      Auto-Select 238.25 GB
```

"IO Error" is the same reason StorageSpaces kicked out the DeskStar and Barracuda, except they were paired with "Lost Communication".  It's the reason I replaced all SATA cables. However "Failed Media" is something I don't remember seeing in the past (the UltraStar didn't last long enough to pool). In the past with `Lost Communication, IO-Error, OK` I'd risk doing [Reset-PhysicalDisk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/reset-physicaldisk?view=win10-ps). But the command is *sketchy as hell* and a little russian roulette-ish.  It automatically decides a course of action and one of those course of actions is wiping your data instead of rescuing it.

After the first 3 failures, I thought maybe StorageSpaces was just bugged and mis-reporting these failures. I had hoped that as long as I had one extra drive as a hotspare such as the HDN726040ALE614 it'd recover and I could just re-add the volume after it finishes migrating data. But before I did that I decided to test the HDN726040ALE614 and ST4000DM005 outside of the storage pool as regular NTFS volumes. They passed all short manufacturer tests (I didn't try long test because ETA was some ridiculous 30+hrs). However, once I'd try to actually copy files over - eventually the HDN726040ALE614 would start clicking and the ST4000DM005 would do its constant spin-up, click, spin-down routine as shown in the video. While they do this Windows Explorer would go unresponsive and sometimes the entire PC would lock up (mouse and all).

Oddly, even from a complete freeze, I found I could continue by unplugging the SATA cable to unfreeze Windows then re-plug it which would even sometimes break the cycle the drives get stuck in. Typically they just go back at it, but it usually allowed Windows to continue. I'd also have to re-confirm this, but I think it may be an effective way to get StorageSpaces to switch the drive failure reason to "Lost Communication" and allow running `Reset-PhysicalDisk`.

Additionally, as seen in the posted Youtube video, the "Click of Death" is way more likely to occur if the PC is laid horizontal - when horizontal the HDN726040ALE614 is likely to just click away and the PC never boots. And as seen in the 2nd half of the video, when the PC is vertical, the Seagate Barracuda becomes the antagonist.

I have ruled out the PCIe SATA controller as the drives continue to exhibit the behavior when plugged directly into the mobo.

- Can the PSU cause an unstable BUS clock?  What could potentially be causing the BUS fluctuations?
- Can an unstable BUS clock cause HD failure and why are the oldest drives working without issue?
- Are HDD's currently unbelievably unreliable potentially due to the COVID19's impact on manufacturers? Or am I just really unlucky?
- Any advice, recommendations, or courses of action? I'm pretty much stumped.

#### EDIT:

Windows worked all night to recover data from the WD6003FRYZ and move it to the older DeskStars which are now pretty much at full capacity.  Here's what that process sounded like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hP2ec9Nswkk
I'm not sure how it managed because the StorageSpace is 3 columns, which I was under the impression meant there needs to be at least 3 drives.  Performance is however abysmal.  While I still can't get the WD6003FRYZ to throw a SMART error or fail WD Data LifeGuard Diagnostics Quick Test, it does fail the Extended Test pretty quickly.  I'm not sure how a power issue could cause bad sectors? Am I just really unlucky?
[image]

Comment: “Can the PSU cause an unstable BUS clock?” - Yes; “What could potentially be causing the BUS fluctuations?” - You indicated you have bent CPU pins.  You can assume your HDDs were manufactured over a year before the current world events, their failure, has absolutely nothing to do with the world events.

Comment: "You indicated you have bent CPU pins"  - I also indicated I replaced the Motherboard and CPU afterwards.  Was that not clear?  
I remember reading the label of the WD6003FRYZ and being impressed with how recently it was manufactured.  I'd have to pull it to check, but I believe it was just 2-3 months ago.

I don't understand the mechanism by which the PSU can cause the fluctuations and the -2MHz deprecation. And how it only causes new harddrives to fail while the older ones are fine.

Comment: Has there been precedence where the PSU was found to cause these types of fluctuations on several different motherboards? I'd expect each motherboard to behave differently.  Not the exact same.  I'd like to know more about this and I have not been able to find anything?  Also how it happened after a move.  It just all strikes me as odd.

Comment: SATA power is provided directly from the PSU, only SATA data, is connected to the motherboard.  Your question is extremely long, you mentioned hardware replacement at the start of it, but then described the bent pins.  Seems like the bent pins is unrelated information to the current problem if both the motherboard and cpu was replaced (not simply sent in for warranty service)

Comment: Yes the length is why I didn't mention some additional things.  I have measured the voltages with a Fluke meter and they are in spec. I'd need an Oscilloscope to get any more accurate. The SATA data cables clock rate is tied to the Bus Clock. Which I believe it the cause of the IO errors.  But what strikes me as odd is that the drives appeared to have actually failed.  I'd expect them to work in a stable environment. The bent pin is info about things I tried before the mobo replacement, and how even replacement didn't fix the issue. It's meant to show how it affects multiple motherboards

Comment: The "BCLK problem" is likely just measurement error combined with perfectly normal clock drift. It is not a problem, it is unlikely to be caused by your power supply, and it is not likely related to any of your other problems. Clocks drift with temperature, motherboards use "good enough" (probably up to 2 to 5% from actual) clock measuring devices rather than 100% accurate ones, and your CPU should be more than capable of dealing with a 1-2% drift with no side effects. It it likely unrelated to your power supply problems.

Comment: The odd part is that the BCLK was stable and would only drift 0.1MHz from what was set in the BIOS before the move as opposed to the now up to 6MHz drift (if I set 103 in bios it will swing between 97 and 103).  And the Hard Disk failures coincided with the new clock drift issue.

Comment: From your video, I'm wondering what the system temperatures are like (wall-pc-desk board looks like poor ventillation, and a bottom fan on carpet isn't going to be great). also, how close and loud is that subwoofer is during normal usage? is it magnetically shielded?... [do the parts go here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faDQP.jpg) What's on the other side of that wall?

Comment: I would remove all drives from this computer - data is precious (unless you don't care)... use separate power, and separate interface, have them on a desk with good airflow (e.g: a USB toaster / dock with a fan pointed at it).

Comment: Yes PC goes there, when there it is about 4in above the ground. Sub(Z5300e)  is in normal location and shielded. 
Temperatures are typically 

* HDDs&SSDs: 30-34C. May reach 38C when CPU & GPU at full load for hours.  
* CPU:  24-32C @ 15-25watt idle, 70C @ full 90watt load, 93C @ Prime95 AVX 130watt peak.
* GPU: 48C @ 40watt idle, 70C @ 200watt load, 74C @ 220watt peak.
Full Specs with current temps here: https://bl.ocks.org/DerekZiemba/raw/13cd104e66322d01a2f21cf207978282/